# Mount file ind folder with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

On the docker host is a folder for an web side: /var/html

Inside is a config file, named config.yaml => /var/html/config.yaml

It works with

```
volumes:
- /var/html/:/var/html
```

The config.yaml is mounted with the folder.

Now, on docker host, I have the file stored in /etc/foo/config.yaml

Is there anyway in docker-compose to do that? That does not work:

```
volumes:
- /var/html/:/var/html
- /etc/foo/config.yaml:/var/html/config.yaml
```

Any other idea except mounting to a different volume and copying on startup of container?

Comment: Have you tried to mount the whole directory:
- /etc/foo/:/var/html/

Comment: It is rejected then: Duplicate Mount Points

Comment: Maybe do the trick to copy locally (on host): cp /etc/foo/config.yaml /var/html/ and then mount only one volume, eg. - /var/html/:/var/html/

Comment: Yes this way is quite ok. As the Container might modify the file, a copy back is also required the container shuts down (/var/html/config.yaml => /etc/foo/config.yaml). I think to mount it to a different location and handle file copy inside the container might be more consitent